# adb version clash

Tags: command-line, versions

i have two version of Android Debug Bridge version installed.

> which i  think is causing the issue.
>
> > when i enter.

`adb devices  // in terminal`

terminal get stuck in next line.

infact what ever command i enter for Android Debug Bridge it get stuck.

the whole system doesn't get stuck.

with `ctrl+c` press in terminal can recover. 
and can apply different commands.

how can i deleted one version of adb without affecting the other.

Comment: What? Anytime 2-versions of adb worked togheter in your computer? Is not one disturbing the other?

Comment: i am also trying  to find out when ever i type command for adb it get stuck over there.
if you can help me delete one version with out effecting the other. it would be great relief.

Comment: You could see that by Synaptic. Open it and search by name. So you may decide which version you want to remove.